# Import nodes programmatically without administrative access

Tags: migrations

I have a database of drupal installation, containing around 300 nodes. I need the nodes from  that database to be added into another Drupal installation. How can this be done programmatically?

I have only a SQL file, and I don't have administrative access to the Drupal installation.

Comment: if you want to do it grammatically you should look for the [migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) module.

Comment: Have you looked at the Feeds module? http://drupal.org/project/feeds/

Comment: If the OP doesn't have administrative access to the site, it is probable he cannot install new modules.

Comment: @indrock  I dont have admin access, only the database is with me

Comment: @PatrickKenny  I dont have admin access, only the database is with me

Comment: Guess it's only the source system you have no access, right? What abaout the destination? Is it a drupal installation?

Comment: Can you make it more clear about what access you have? Drupal Installation Directory and Drupal site admin. Which one do you have access?

Comment: @BetaRide I have got mysql dump, i.e an sql file of all the tables and its contents. I have got full access of the destination drupal site ,including mysql,ftp and admin sections

Comment: @user1301840  I have got mysql dump, i.e an sql file of all the tables and its contents

Comment: So you only have access to the database of the new drupal site with the original drupal site's sql file?

Comment: @user1301840 I have got db, drupal admin and ftp access of new drupal site and only the sql file of the old site. Both sites are in drupal 7

Comment: take a look at this, I haven't tried it, but it seems fitting your objective. [Backup and Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate)

Comment: the above solutions regarding feeds or migrate or spot-on, this is a pretty easy task to dump out any arbitrary content once you have admin access. since you have the actual database, is there a reason you can't manually change it to give you admin access (i.e. http://drupal.org/node/44164/)?

Comment: I think only coding for node export and saving node  can achieve this

Comment: I think you have to read the file programmatically  and save each node in a loop or a batch operation